# OpenDaylight integration with OpenStack: Missing table in database

Tags: openstack, opendaylight

I have the following OpenStack infrastructure:

- 2 compute nodes
- 1 controller node

This work fine, I can create network, router, vm, etc... Now, I want to add an OpenDaylight controller in the cloud infrastructure using the service NetVirt. I follow the officiel OpenDaylight guide: http://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/netvirt/en/latest/openstack-guide/openstack-with-netvirt.html#installing-opendaylight-on-an-existing-openstack

Every step in the installation is done without any probleme. I can see the open vSwitch  on each nodes managed by my SDN controller. At the end, when i restart Neutron to test if everything is working, I have the following behavior:

```
[root@controller01 ~(keystone_admin)]# neutron router-create router1
Created a new router:
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                   | Value                                |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up          | True                                 |
| availability_zone_hints |                                      |
| availability_zones      |                                      |
| created_at              | 2018-04-18T08:50:30Z                 |
| description             |                                      |
| distributed             | False                                |
| external_gateway_info   |                                      |
| flavor_id               |                                      |
| ha                      | False                                |
| id                      | 611aa06a-dca6-4637-98c9-0b9882762bd2 |
| name                    | router1                              |
| project_id              | 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c     |
| revision_number         | 3                                    |
| routes                  |                                      |
| status                  | ACTIVE                               |
| tenant_id               | 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c     |
| updated_at              | 2018-04-18T08:50:30Z                 |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+

[root@controller01 ~(keystone_admin)]# neutron net-create private
Created a new network:
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | True                                 |
| availability_zone_hints   |                                      |
| availability_zones        |                                      |
| created_at                | 2018-04-18T08:50:48Z                 |
| description               |                                      |
| id                        | d0333a22-dd9c-4522-8597-e605d0d4a5f5 |
| ipv4_address_scope        |                                      |
| ipv6_address_scope        |                                      |
| mtu                       | 1450                                 |
| name                      | private                              |
| project_id                | 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c     |
| provider:network_type     | vxlan                                |
| provider:physical_network |                                      |
| provider:segmentation_id  | 78                                   |
| revision_number           | 2                                    |
| router:external           | False                                |
| shared                    | False                                |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   |                                      |
| tags                      |                                      |
| tenant_id                 | 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c     |
| updated_at                | 2018-04-18T08:50:48Z                 |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+

[root@controller01 ~]# curl -u admin:admin http://10.10.10.68:8080/controller/nb/v2/neutron/networks
{
   "networks" : [ {
      "id" : "4ad0b7ef-67b3-47ef-8595-4de5e24570a2",
      "tenant_id" : "8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c",
      "project_id" : "8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c",
      "revision_number" : 2,
      "name" : "private",
      "admin_state_up" : true,
      "status" : "ACTIVE",
      "shared" : false,
      "router:external" : false,
      "provider:network_type" : "vxlan",
      "provider:segmentation_id" : "73",
      "segments" : [ ]
   } ]

[root@controller01 ~(keystone_admin)]# neutron subnet-create private --name=private_subnet 10.10.5.0/24
Request Failed: internal server error while processing your request.
Neutron server returns request_ids: ['req-fb242532-76df-4283-98d0-0928ce958013']
```

Looking at neutron log file:

```
2018-04-18 10:51:15.447 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'neutron.opendaylight_periodic_task' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT opendaylight_periodic_task.state AS opendaylight_periodic_task_state, opendaylight_periodic_task.processing_operation AS opendaylight_periodic_task_processing_operation, opendaylight_periodic_task.task AS opendaylight_periodic_task_task, opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated AS opendaylight_periodic_task_lock_updated \nFROM opendaylight_periodic_task \nWHERE opendaylight_periodic_task.task = %(task_1)s AND opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated <= %(lock_updated_1)s'] [parameters: {u'task_1': 'hostconfig', u'lock_updated_1': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 10, 50, 45)}]
2018-04-18 10:51:15.447 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall 
2018-04-18 10:51:16.379 30461 ERROR neutron.db.metering.metering_rpc [req-488bf35c-8e90-49cf-9517-28e736dea563 - - - - -] Unable to find agent controller01.
2018-04-18 10:51:38.478 30457 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-211fe59c-e7fd-4d03-8f88-20f186ff7f75 aaa93c4dbc4a4ec090f71e9061571a44 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c - - -] Option "rabbit_host" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal (Replaced by [DEFAULT]/transport_url).  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2018-04-18 10:51:38.479 30457 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-211fe59c-e7fd-4d03-8f88-20f186ff7f75 aaa93c4dbc4a4ec090f71e9061571a44 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c - - -] Option "rabbit_port" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal (Replaced by [DEFAULT]/transport_url).  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2018-04-18 10:51:38.480 30457 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-211fe59c-e7fd-4d03-8f88-20f186ff7f75 aaa93c4dbc4a4ec090f71e9061571a44 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c - - -] Option "rabbit_userid" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal (Replaced by [DEFAULT]/transport_url).  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2018-04-18 10:51:38.480 30457 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-211fe59c-e7fd-4d03-8f88-20f186ff7f75 aaa93c4dbc4a4ec090f71e9061571a44 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c - - -] Option "rabbit_password" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal (Replaced by [DEFAULT]/transport_url).  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2018-04-18 10:51:38.481 30457 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-211fe59c-e7fd-4d03-8f88-20f186ff7f75 aaa93c4dbc4a4ec090f71e9061571a44 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c - - -] Option "rabbit_use_ssl" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated. Use option "ssl" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit".
2018-04-18 10:51:38.507 30457 INFO neutron.quota [req-211fe59c-e7fd-4d03-8f88-20f186ff7f75 aaa93c4dbc4a4ec090f71e9061571a44 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c - - -] Loaded quota_driver: <neutron.db.quota.driver.DbQuotaDriver object at 0x6379210>.
2018-04-18 10:51:38.602 30457 INFO neutron.wsgi [req-211fe59c-e7fd-4d03-8f88-20f186ff7f75 aaa93c4dbc4a4ec090f71e9061571a44 8e20ff8abaf14250aab8aa4db37f5b3c - - -] 10.10.10.68 - - [18/Apr/2018 10:51:38] "POST /v2.0/routers.json HTTP/1.1" 201 697 0.272735
2018-04-18 10:51:45.465 30467 INFO networking_odl.journal.periodic_task [req-b476cffc-5bce-4893-b3c0-1a2f4f77f963 - - - - -] Starting hostconfig periodic task.
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall [req-b476cffc-5bce-4893-b3c0-1a2f4f77f963 - - - - -] Fixed interval looping call 'networking_odl.journal.periodic_task.PeriodicTask.execute_ops' failed: ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'neutron.opendaylight_periodic_task' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT opendaylight_periodic_task.state AS opendaylight_periodic_task_state, opendaylight_periodic_task.processing_operation AS opendaylight_periodic_task_processing_operation, opendaylight_periodic_task.task AS opendaylight_periodic_task_task, opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated AS opendaylight_periodic_task_lock_updated \nFROM opendaylight_periodic_task \nWHERE opendaylight_periodic_task.task = %(task_1)s AND opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated <= %(lock_updated_1)s'] [parameters: {u'task_1': 'hostconfig', u'lock_updated_1': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 10, 51, 15)}]
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_service/loopingcall.py", line 66, in func
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networking_odl/journal/periodic_task.py", line 96, in execute_ops
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     if not forced and self.task_already_executed_recently(context):
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networking_odl/journal/periodic_task.py", line 73, in task_already_executed_recently
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     context.session, self.task, self.interval)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networking_odl/db/db.py", line 168, in was_periodic_task_executed_recently
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     (now - delta >= (models.OpenDaylightPeriodicTask.lock_updated))
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2664, in one_or_none
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     ret = list(self)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2736, in __iter__
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2751, in _execute_and_instances
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     compiled_sql, distilled_params
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     context)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1337, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     util.raise_from_cause(newraise, exc_info)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 200, in raise_from_cause
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     context)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     result = self._query(query)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     conn.query(q)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 841, in query
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1029, in _read_query_result
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     result.read()
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1312, in read
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 991, in _read_packet
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     packet.check_error()
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     raise errorclass(errno, errval)
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'neutron.opendaylight_periodic_task' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT opendaylight_periodic_task.state AS opendaylight_periodic_task_state, opendaylight_periodic_task.processing_operation AS opendaylight_periodic_task_processing_operation, opendaylight_periodic_task.task AS opendaylight_periodic_task_task, opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated AS opendaylight_periodic_task_lock_updated \nFROM opendaylight_periodic_task \nWHERE opendaylight_periodic_task.task = %(task_1)s AND opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated <= %(lock_updated_1)s'] [parameters: {u'task_1': 'hostconfig', u'lock_updated_1': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 10, 51, 15)}]
2018-04-18 10:51:45.476 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall 
2018-04-18 10:51:56.377 30462 ERROR neutron.db.metering.metering_rpc [req-488bf35c-8e90-49cf-9517-28e736dea563 - - - - -] Unable to find agent controller01.
2018-04-18 10:52:15.497 30467 INFO networking_odl.journal.periodic_task [req-b476cffc-5bce-4893-b3c0-1a2f4f77f963 - - - - -] Starting hostconfig periodic task.
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall [req-b476cffc-5bce-4893-b3c0-1a2f4f77f963 - - - - -] Fixed interval looping call 'networking_odl.journal.periodic_task.PeriodicTask.execute_ops' failed: ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'neutron.opendaylight_periodic_task' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT opendaylight_periodic_task.state AS opendaylight_periodic_task_state, opendaylight_periodic_task.processing_operation AS opendaylight_periodic_task_processing_operation, opendaylight_periodic_task.task AS opendaylight_periodic_task_task, opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated AS opendaylight_periodic_task_lock_updated \nFROM opendaylight_periodic_task \nWHERE opendaylight_periodic_task.task = %(task_1)s AND opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated <= %(lock_updated_1)s'] [parameters: {u'task_1': 'hostconfig', u'lock_updated_1': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 10, 51, 45)}]
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_service/loopingcall.py", line 66, in func
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networking_odl/journal/periodic_task.py", line 96, in execute_ops
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     if not forced and self.task_already_executed_recently(context):
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networking_odl/journal/periodic_task.py", line 73, in task_already_executed_recently
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     context.session, self.task, self.interval)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networking_odl/db/db.py", line 168, in was_periodic_task_executed_recently
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     (now - delta >= (models.OpenDaylightPeriodicTask.lock_updated))
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2664, in one_or_none
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     ret = list(self)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2736, in __iter__
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2751, in _execute_and_instances
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     compiled_sql, distilled_params
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     context)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1337, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     util.raise_from_cause(newraise, exc_info)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 200, in raise_from_cause
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     context)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     result = self._query(query)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     conn.query(q)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 841, in query
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1029, in _read_query_result
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     result.read()
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1312, in read
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 991, in _read_packet
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     packet.check_error()
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     raise errorclass(errno, errval)
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'neutron.opendaylight_periodic_task' doesn't exist") [SQL: u'SELECT opendaylight_periodic_task.state AS opendaylight_periodic_task_state, opendaylight_periodic_task.processing_operation AS opendaylight_periodic_task_processing_operation, opendaylight_periodic_task.task AS opendaylight_periodic_task_task, opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated AS opendaylight_periodic_task_lock_updated \nFROM opendaylight_periodic_task \nWHERE opendaylight_periodic_task.task = %(task_1)s AND opendaylight_periodic_task.lock_updated <= %(lock_updated_1)s'] [parameters: {u'task_1': 'hostconfig', u'lock_updated_1': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 10, 51, 45)}]
2018-04-18 10:52:15.506 30467 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall 
[root@controller01 ~(keystone_admin)]#
```

So it look like creating object work, but they are not stored in the database, and so it is impossible to reference them. In the same way, i can create several times a router/network with the same name, and I can't list my router or network.

The missing table, `opendaylight_periodic_task`, is supposed to be create by the python module `networking-odl`, which is installed.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you run the `neutron-db-manage` command after resetting the neutron DB? Following the official guide this is the only command I could guess that would create that table: `/usr/local/bin/neutron-db-manage --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini upgrade head`

Comment: @vabada Yes, I did it.

Comment: Might be worth re-running the migration, in case something was wrong with the original run

Comment: @Steve I did the installation like fifteen times, always with the same result. (starting each time from a backup with a clean working OpenStack).